# Ajax Auto complete Css works fine in iis and the server but not in local machine

Tags: c#, ajax

I have used ajax auto completeextender in my program well its works fine no problem. After hosting to iis server i checked it in iis there also works fine. But when i accessing from brower autocomplete works fine but css is not working,

I am using external style sheet this is the css i hv used

```
/*AutoComplete flyout */
.autocomplete_completionListElement
{
    margin : 0px!important ;
    background-color : inherit ;
    color : windowtext ;
    border : buttonshadow ;
    border-width : 1px ;
    border-style : solid ;
    cursor : 'default' ;
    overflow : auto ;
    height : 200px ;
    font-family : Tahoma ;
    font-size : small ;
    text-align : left ;
    list-style-type : none ;
    }
/* AutoComplete highlighted item */
.autocomplete_highlightedListItem
   {
    background-color : #ffff99 ;
    color : black ;
    padding : 1px ;
    }

    /* AutoComplete item */
.autocomplete_listItem
    {
    background-color : window ;
    color : windowtext ;
    padding : 1px ;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. The problem is with the virtual directory in the iis.Make a new iis virtual directory in the iis then you won't get the above problem